# Error: FB.login() called before calling FB.init()

Tags: javascript, authentication, facebook

I use this Facebook Login Button code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'myActualId',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
</script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="false" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

But the debug console gives me this error:
FB.login() called before calling FB.init().

I made a test page so my error can be seen:
http://www.comehike.com/test_fb_connect.php

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're loading the Facebook script all.js twice. It should be loaded only once.

Comment: How do you know its twice?  Which is the first and second time? - Thanks!

Comment: When I Viewed Source i saw a reference to http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1 and about 20 lines later I saw a reference to http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

Comment: Now when I View Source, i see only the first reference (the one with #xfbml=1).

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, I was indeed calling it twice.

Comment: No the real problem was you input the wrong Facebook APP ID

Comment: @FarisRayhan The OP was calling the script twice, so my answer was correct for his situation. Someone else's answer was correct for your situation.

Answer (score 48):

If you pass the non existing FB app key to init() then only you get the error of 'FB.login() called before calling FB.init()'

Make sure, you hadn't been doing the same.

Comment: Can i check somehow if init succeed or not?

Comment: ah pretty funny for a moment I expected a $ 8.000.000.000,- revenue company to have the resources to write `if (appId.isInvalid()) throw new Error('invalid appId')`. Tnx FB <3

Comment: Hello, I'm a time traveler from the year 2021 and wanted to let you know that while this still hasn't been fixed, everything else has gotten worse. Try and enjoy the next few years because it's going to get weird.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as no one on the interwebs was able to answer my question, I wiped out the old Facebook app entirely (on my developers.facebook.com account) and just made a new app from scratch and made a totally new one.

After that, the basic code did the job

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem in my case was APP-ID, When you try to post at fb withoud App-ID you'll get same.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32554372)

Answer (score -7):

This worked for me

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  FB.init({
    appId  : true,
    status : false, // check login status
    cookie : false, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });
</script>
```

Comment: appId should be the facebook application's ID. This shouldn't work.