# Getting error while trying to implement facebook social login in angular9 while using it in http

Tags: angular, facebook-login, angular-social-login

I'm trying to implement Facebook social login in angular9 using angularx-social-login. But I'm getting this error.
thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: FB.login() called before calling FB.init()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910974/error-fb-login-called-before-calling-fb-init)

Comment: No this is not similar to the question which you mention

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your pages is not served under https. Even it is localhost in order to use fb login you have to use https. Also it is the same for every social login(google,fb,ms,etc). This restiction is due to security reasons.

In order to server you dev environment in https you have to add you cert to the server.

I found this tutorial in order to genereate for localhost
https://medium.com/@richardr39/using-angular-cli-to-serve-over-https-locally-70dab07417c8